# Comparing dates (older, newer, or the same)

Tags: php

Date 1: dd/mm/yy

Date 2: dd/mm/yy

Date 3: dd/mm/yy

Say I have:

```
$date1 = 04/07/2014;
$date2 = 04/06/2014;
$date3 = 04/07/2014;
```

What would be the most efficient method to determine if date 2 is between or equal to date 1 and date 3 using PHP? In other words, what is the best way to check if the dates are the same, newer, or older than another date

Comment: There are several possible ways (create date objects, reformat into a sortable string format, …) – and “efficiency” in regard to performance(?) is hardly a criterion for such a minimal operation, so use what suits you best in terms of readability.

Answer (score 3):

The best way is to convert date into timestamp, then it will be easy to compare.
Try to use 

`$time1 = strtotime("dd/mm/yy");
$time2 = strtotime("dd/mm/yy");`

Comment: You could also put those in as floats, and check which one is bigger, smaller, or the same using a basic if/while statement/loop, it really depends on what he is using this for though. (he would have to change to YYYY/MM/DD and he could also use an int)

Answer (score 0):

Well, this really depends on what you are using this for, what I personally did (when checking dates in a MySQL database for a scheduling website I made) I used the following:

```
    $publishDate = $row['year'] . $row['month'] . $row['day'];
    $now = date("Ynj");//four number year, two number month, two number day (YYYY/MM/DD)
```

You could do the same, input your date as Ynj (See PHP documentation on ***date*** [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php)) 
and then compare them. This may help put this whole idea in context; this is the code I wrote for my website:

```
  $publishDate = $row['year'] . $row['month'] . $row['day'];
  $now = date("Ynj");//four number year, two number month, two number day (YYYY/MM/DD)

  if($now > $publishDate)
  {
    //This is saying that right now, is greater than when this was added
    $msg = "This date is smaller than the time now, which means it is in the past";
  }

  if ($now < $publishDate)
  {
    echo "This date is greater than the time now, which means it is in the future.";
  }
  if ($now == $publishDate)
  {
    echo "Date is the same";
  }
```

If you add more context to your question I am sure I can help allot more! Good luck